# How can I set TextBox.SelectionStart after TextChanged?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
    textBox.Text = new string(textBox.Text.Distinct().ToArray());
    textBox.Select(selectionStart, 0);
}
```

This code works as it's supposed to:

1. if I insert a new unique character (a character that is not in the string *textBox.Text*) at the end of the *textBox.Text*
2. if I try to insert the character that is in the string *textBox.Text* at the end of the *textBox.Text*
3. if I insert a new unique character in the middle of the string *textBox.Text*

But this code does not work correctly when I try to insert a character (that is in the string *textBox.Text*) in the middle of a string *textBox.Text*. The selection cursor moves to the right, although it shouldn't, because the text doesn't change.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Probably because the TextChanged event doesn't suppress the move of the caret to the right whatever you do to the string

Comment: If the idea is to have unique chars in that text box, then prevent entering the duplicate `e.KeyChar` (skip the control chars) in the `KeyPress` event by setting `e.Handled = true;`. Nothing will be entered so the caret won't move a char. A better solution is to create a custom `TextBox` to handle the `WM_PASTE` messages in `WndProc` override to prevent pasting the duplicate chars as well.

Comment: @EylM I have a string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ". I want to achieve that when i'm typing or pasting text from the clipboard to the place where the caret is located, characters that are already in my string are not added. Moreover, I do not want the order of my letters to change if the string has not been changed.

Comment: ```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox.Text.Contains(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```
this solves the problem with typing. Now i have to find solution for pasting from the clipboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextChanged event cannot suppress the move of the caret to the right. It is its default behavior. But you can compensate adding one line of code inside the TextChanged event and modifying the selectionStart value

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
    int cnt = textBox.Text.GroupBy(t => t).Any(x => x.Count() > 1) ? -1 : 0;
    textBox.Text = new string(textBox.Text.Distinct().ToArray());
    textBox.Select(selectionStart + cnt, 0);
}
```

The key line calculates if we need to compensate for the right move of the caret first grouping the characters in the textbox and then counting if any group has a count bigger than 1. If this is the case the selectionStart variable is adjusted to compensate.

As you have discovered this approach fails short in keeping the characters in their original position. If you try to insert an existing character before one already present the code above keeps the first one and removes the last one.

If you want to keep the last one then you should use the KeyDown event or the KeyPress.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char c = (char)e.KeyValue;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = textBox.Text.Contains(c);
}
```

And if you need to process also the Paste command then you should write your own TextBox class and override the WndProc method called by the Windows API when you press CTRL+V or select the Paste menu

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            var pasteText = Clipboard.GetText().ToArray();
            var currText = this.Text.ToArray();
            var newText = pasteText.Except(currText).ToArray();
            Clipboard.SetText(new string(newText));
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to add an instance of MyTextBox to your forms instead of the standard TextBox.

Comment: your code resolved the issue with the caret. But there is another problem. 
For example, let's say there is a string textBox.Text: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
I place the caret between 'M' and 'N' . And if I type a letter from O to Z then the letters are swapped, which should not be.

Comment: Then you can't do this just using the TextChanged event. When the event triggers you don't know if you have added the O between the M and N or the O between N and P. You need to work on KeyDown event that gives you the code of the character just typed

Comment: But the fact is that this string can be changed not only by entering from the keyboard, but also by pasting text from the clipboard. That's why I chose TextChanged event

Comment: If you need to handle the message WM_PASTE received by the TextBox (the one sent by the Windows API when you press CTRL+V or use the Paste menu) you need to override the WndProc method but this requires you to create a new class derived from a TextBox and add the TextBox to your form from code.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
    int originalTextLength = textBox.Text.Length;
    textBox.Text = new string(textBox.Text.Distinct().ToArray());
    int lengthDif = originalTextLength - textBox.Text.Length;
    textBox.Select(selectionStart - lengthDif, 0);
}
```

Basically, it checks if the length was modified from the original entered text (before the extra character(s) were removed). If it was, it moves the cursor to compensate for any characters removed.

Comment: it works, but i Have new problem.  For example, let's say there is a string textBox.Text: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" I place the caret between 'M' and 'N' . And if I type a letter from O to Z then the letters are swapped, which should not be.